# Gestor web a-base

Tags: crm

Estoy en esta situación: tengo que hacer el mantenimiento y programación de una web de una empresa. Continuar el trabajo del compañero informático que se ha marchado de la empresa. La parte de administración de la web esta hecha con un gestor de contenido denominado a-base, cuyo logotipo os muestro[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro por ninguna parte información sobre este gestor, ni siquiera metiendo el logo en Google Lens. Alguno tiene noticia de este tipo de gestor. Estoy en un marrón considerable
Muchas gracias compañeros

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.